# How to run the JOGL code on the GPU?

Tags: gpu, cpu, jogl

How to run the JOGL code on the GPU?How to Check whether the JOGL code is Running on the CPU or GPU?How to Select the particular GPU When multiple GPU are present ?

Comment: Shader code runs on the GPU. JOGL is an OpenGL library for Java. It will help you execute shader code, but if you're thinking it will run Java code on the GPU, well, that's not how OpenGL works

Comment: Thanks Alex,I got the Answer for First Question ,can you please also let me know How to Check whether the JOGL code is Running on the CPU or GPU?How to Select the particular GPU When multiple GPU are present?

Comment: Please post one question per SO question.

Answer (score 1):

JOGL allows to choose a profile and some capabilities, they are used to pick a driver and some of them aren't hardware accelerated. You can use [the boolean parameter "favorHardwareRasterizer" of this method](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GLProfile.html#getMaxFixedFunc(boolean)) as an hint to indicate to JOGL that you prefer using an hardware accelerated (GPU) profile.

[GLContext.isHardwareRasterizer](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GLContext.html#isHardwareRasterizer()) tells you whether you benefit of hardware acceleration. GL.glGetString(GL.GL_RENDERER) and GL.glGetString(GL.GL_VENDOR) can help you to get some information about the renderer and the vendor of the OpenGL driver.

You can't pick a particular GPU. There is no support of NVidia GPU affinity yet. "multiple GPUs" is vague, it can designate Optimus, SLI or Crossfire.

Rather ask your JOGL specific question on [our official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org/). Only a few contributors and maintainers come here.

Comment: I'll post the further answers here: http://forum.jogamp.org/How-to-run-the-JOGL-code-on-the-GPU-td4038792.html